# Is it beneficial to use the last $N$ data points to train an RL agent?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Given that an environment in reinforcement learning is a [Markov Decision Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process) (MDP), are there ever any cases where it is beneficial (or indeed where it makes sense) to use the last $N>1$ data points to train the agent rather than just the current data point?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called [multi-step learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01327) and can  often lead to faster learning.